# npm install express-generator

Tags: express, npm

I am trying to install an express node-postgres application, but I am getting the following error:

```
module.js:549
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'sorted-object'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express- 
generator/bin/express-cli.js:10:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I am not sure where to go to look for the solution to this error. Should I just delete and reinstall node and npm or is it more simple than that?

Comment: what command are you typing in?

Comment: sudo express node-postgres-app

Comment: No need for `sudo`.

Comment: same result regardless of sudo

Comment: What do `npm -v` and `npm list -g --depth=0 | grep express` output?

Comment: npm -v gives me 6.2.0 and npm list -g --depth=0 | grep express gives me a massive error log